# while animate one image animate another image respectively

Tags: jquery

I'm using a plugin for image slider and there is not navigation buttons like this `O O O O`. So I wanted to make using jquery and having a problem.[This is the plugin I'm using](http://www.joomlahill.com/demos/1-images-crawler). I want to take the picture to left of the div. So here is summarized

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3NPeT/)

---

> .img4 should be shown at left of the div when clicked to .li4

---

I think for what I want should be set of position of images and call scroll function to that position but no idea how to do.....

**Update**

---

Okay I'm cleared now I applied the following and its working

```
$('#banner .img4').parent('div').animate({left: 0},1000); // animates to whole div

$('#banner .img4').animate({left: 0},1000); // this is not working why?
```

But I need to animate to images so that when I animate to .img4 the previous images are also to be animated. How can I do that?

Comment: do you mean something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/3NPeT/1/

Comment: Yes something like that and I tried too but images are having gap when clicked I think I should use scroll function.

Comment: it's really unclear what you trying to achieve, but in you question above you should specify where to offset to (top or bottom and left or right), and `orverflow: hidden` would prevent them to show next to your `li`. But what do you mean `images are having gap when clicked` - I'm not sure....

Comment: the colored divs are scrolling as I'm using plugin and want to be at the left : 0 of the div when clicked.

Comment: you mean you want `img4` to scroll to the beginning of `banner` when `li4` is clicked?

Comment: yes exactly that but previous images should also be scrolled i.e. hidden(scrolled) so this must be used scroll function...

Comment: I tried .scrollLeft(); but not working...

Comment: this needs to refer to plugin natural settings and use them to perform action (i.e. `ImageCrawler.start('img4');`). I am not familiar with this plugin, so cannot help... unless you dig deeper into the code